# In Ruby, why does the .index method work with a "false" value?

Tags: ruby, indexing, methods, boolean

Looking at this code I don't understand why the .index method works when, inside the {}, is returned false by the vowel? method below.

The vowel? method returns a true/false value. If it's true the index position where the vowel was found is saved to split the word at that position.

For the word "word" it doesn't find a vowel until at index 1 so what happens with the value "false" returned for "w" (index 0)?

Why does the program not crash when it returns false instead of a number?

```
def louchebemize_word(word)
  random_suffix = %w[em é ji oc ic uche ès].sample
  return word if word.size == 1 # do not translate one-letter word
  if vowel? word[0] 
    return "l#{word}#{random_suffix}" # word beginning with vowel
  else
    # word beginning with 1 or more consonants
    first_vowel_index = word.chars.index { |letter| vowel?(letter) } 
    beginning = word[0...first_vowel_index]
    ending = word[first_vowel_index...word.size]
    "l#{ending}#{beginning}#{random_suffix}"
  end
end

def vowel?(letter)
  return %w[a e i o u].include? letter
end

puts louchebemize_word("word")
```

Comment: Is that really a [mre]? Or could you perhaps have used only `'word'.chars.index { |l| %w[a e i o u].include?(l) }` to demonstrate your question and left out the remaining unnecessary 15 lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

From the Ruby docs for the [`index` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-index):

> If a block is given instead of an argument, returns the *index* of the first object for which the block returns `true`. Returns `nil` if no match is found.

If your question is "why does the program not crash when it returns false?", then your question is based on false premises.

First, Ruby will not crash from unexpected return values. It'll just return them, and your code will handle or not handle those return values.

Second, `index` never returns false instead of a number. It returns a number or `nil`.

It sounds like there's just a misunderstanding about what `index` returns. Whatever code you have running inside the block will have some return value, but that value is ignored unless it is `true`. If it's `true` then `index` returns a number. (the index of the value in the array) If it's anything other than `true` then `index` will continue iterating over the array. If the entire array is iterated and no `true` value was returned then `index` returns `nil`.

So to answer your question *what happens with the value "false" returned for "w" (index 0)?*, `false` is ignored.